# Finding index by while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, while-loop

How can I print index from a list by a **while loop** (not for)?

*example 1:*

```
Lst=[1,2,3,4,5]

c=2
```

In this case, I want python(2.7) to print the index of numbers in Lst that can be devided by c. (lst[**1**],lst[**4**])

*example 2:*

```
Lst=[1,3,3,3,5]

c=2
```

In this case, I want python(2.7) to print '**None**'.

Comment: I answered, but overlooked the "by while loop" part which makes your question a "write a dumb code for my homework assignment" question. Do it yourself. Note: a while loop is the worst control structure for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you are looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

Lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

c=2
i = 0
res = []
while i in range(len(Lst)):
        if Lst[i] % 2 == 0:
                res.append(Lst[i])
        i+=1
if len(res) > 0:
        print res
else:
        print "None"
```